# Длительная авторизация Yii

Tags: авторизация, yii

Здравствуйте. Использовал "рецепт" авторизации Yii. Специально не передавал куки:

```
Yii::app()->user->login($identity);
```

т.к. это веб-приложение и незачем сохранять. Такая авторизация должна длиться по времени, равному длительности сессии. Но заходя даже через 1-2 дня я остаюсь авторизованным. В php.ini сессия по дефолту - 24 минуты. Куки проверял - пусто (кроме PHPSESSID).
Авторизация проверяется через Yii::app()->user->isGuest, т.е. проверяется наличие в переменной $_SESSION['id'], который устанавливается при входе.

Как это объяснить и решить проблему?

П.С. Проверялось на локальном и хостинге.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проверьте в конфигурационном файле

```
'allowAutoLogin' => false
```

Иначе `yii` использует `cookies based authentication`.

Comment: @Mobyman, действительно стоял такой конфиг. А откуда он брал куки, если в браузере вроде не было видно?